# Avoid xgb.cv from using testing data when used with the argument early_stopping_rounds (or alternative work-arounds)

Tags: r, xgboost, cross-validation

I am currently working with the `xgboost` package in `R`.
One thing that started bothering me was when I set the `early_stopping_rounds` parameters in the `xgboost::xgb.cv` function. It seemed that the `1` fold left out for validation/testing was used to determine when to stop. This seems counterintuitive as CV is to evaluate model performance on out of sample data.

*(Disclaimer I am mainly interested in using this for hyperparameter tuning)*

Here is a small example that runs `xgboost::xgb.cv` on simulated data and then compares the predictions on the real data. It shows that the predictions on the test folds are comparable with real data when `early_stopping_rounds` stops the training.

```r
# Load packages
## install.packages('vip')
library(xgboost)
library(purrr)

# For rep
set.seed(1)
# Generate some data
sim_data <- vip::gen_friedman(600)
xgb_input <- sim_data %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  {xgb.DMatrix(.[,!'y' == colnames(.)], label = .[,'y' == colnames(.)])}

# Fit the model
model <- xgb.cv(
  params = list(eta = .4),
  data = xgb_input, 
  nrounds = 100, 
  early_stopping_rounds = 5,
  nfold = 6,
  print_every_n = 28,
  prediction = T
)
#> [1]  train-rmse:9.205993+0.066525    test-rmse:9.291344+0.511701 
#> Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_rmse for early stopping.
#> Will train until test_rmse hasn't improved in 5 rounds.
#> 
#> [29] train-rmse:0.115219+0.010687    test-rmse:1.675245+0.097033 
#> Stopping. Best iteration:
#> [29] train-rmse:0.115219+0.010687    test-rmse:1.675245+0.097033
# Evaluate folds
map_dbl(model$folds,
    ~vip::metric_rmse(sim_data$y[.x], model$pred[.x])
) %>% 
  {cat(paste0(round(mean(.), 5), '+', round(sd(.), 6)))}
#> 1.67524+0.106294
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Question: is there a way to use the utility for `xgb.cv` but setting `1` fold for testing, `1` (different) fold to estimate `early_stopping_rounds`, and `n-2` for training?

Or do I simply have to program such a procedure myself? It is a bit unclear to me from the manual.

Or, is it better to first extract some data to use for the `early_stopping_rounds` (using the `watchlist` flag) and use the remainder for `xgb.cv`? How would this play out in hyperparameter tuning? Would it be better to use a fixed set for the `watchlist` for all parameter settings?

**edit:**
`xgb.cv` does not seem to take the `watchlist` argument. But one could leave some data out for actual testing and predict each `n` models on that data.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your quesiton. The issue is that the test data is being used in model training.

Comment: oh, sorry  I failed to understand your questions correctly. (i deleted my comment)

Comment: Ah, maybe it is a bit unclear =/